# Karma: cannot start chrome

Tags: jasmine, karma-runner, runner

For my angularjs project, trying to use karma+jamine for unit testing. I have installed karma @ local and trying to start from .bin folder. So i'm getting following issue; FYI I'm pasting folder structure along with,

**ERROR:**

```
C:\Workspace\node_modules.bin>karma start ../../karma.conf.js
27 10 2015 09:57:06.461:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
27 10 2015 09:57:06.486:INFO [karma]: Karma v0.13.11 server started at http://localhost:9876/
27 10 2015 09:57:06.500:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
27 10 2015 09:57:07.111:ERROR [launcher]: Cannot start Chrome
27 10 2015 09:57:07.119:INFO [launcher]: Trying to start Chrome again (1/2).
27 10 2015 09:57:07.491:ERROR [launcher]: Cannot start Chrome
27 10 2015 09:57:07.493:INFO [launcher]: Trying to start Chrome again (2/2).
27 10 2015 09:57:08.234:ERROR [launcher]: Cannot start Chrome
27 10 2015 09:57:08.236:ERROR [launcher]: Chrome failed 2 times (cannot start).Giving up.
27 10 2015 09:57:08.633:INFO [Chrome 46.0.2490 (Windows 7 0.0.0)]: Connected on
socket PgWwwQDh6BZ7k9fpAAAA with id 74171654
27 10 2015 09:57:18.954:WARN [Chrome 46.0.2490 (Windows 7 0.0.0)]: Disconnected
(1 times), because no message in 10000 ms.
27 10 2015 09:57:18.957:ERROR [karma]: [TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of
undefined]TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined at _render (C:\Workspace\node_modules\karma\lib\reporters\progress.js:51:26)
at _refresh (C:\Workspace\node_modules\karma\lib\reporters\progress.js:55:34)
at onBrowserComplete (C:\Workspace\node_modules\karma\lib\reporters\prog
ress.js:15:21)
at null. (C:\Workspace\node_modules\karma\lib\events.js:13:22
)
at emitOne (events.js:82:20)
at emit (events.js:169:7)
at null._onTimeout (C:\Workspace\node_modules\karma\lib\browser.js:50:15
)
at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:89:15)
```

**Folder Structure:**
node_modules
src
test
karma.conf
package.json

**karma.conf File**

```
module.exports = function(config) {
config.set({
frameworks: ['jasmine'],
plugins: [
'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
'karma-jasmine',
'karma-coverage',
'karma-chrome-launcher' ,
'karma-firefox-launcher',
'karma-requirejs',
'karma-ie-launcher' 
],
files: [
'src/assets/js/angular.js',
'src/assets/js/angular-mocks.js',
'src/app//.js',
'test/.js'
],
preprocessors: {
'src/app//*.js': ['coverage']
},
reporters: ['progress','coverage'],
coverageReporter: {
type: 'html',
dir: 'coverage'
},
logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
browsers: ['Chrome'],
singleRun: false
});
```

Comment: Is the Chrome browser installed in the default path in your environment?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31966434/karma-chrome-failed-2-times-cannot-start-giving-up/42700178#42700178